# Escape apostrophe in docker command

Tags: bash, docker, escaping, airflow

I`m trying to add variable using docker CLI command in following way:

```
 docker exec -u root  airflowdags_webserver_1 bash -c  "airflow variables --set my_var '{\"test\": \"test\'2\"}'"
```

But getting following error:

> bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
>
> bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I have no any errors if doing one of these commands:

```
docker exec -u root  airflowdags_webserver_1 bash -c  "airflow variables --set my_var '{\"test\": \"test\`2\"}'"
```

or

```
docker exec -u root  airflowdags_webserver_1 bash -c  "airflow variables --set my_var '{\"test\": \"test2\"}'"
```

How can I escape apostrophe in the "test'2" value to avoid the error?

Comment: So if you `printf X"airflow variables --set my_var '{\"test\": \"test\'2\"}'"X\\n` you'll get `Xairflow variables --set my_var '{"test": "test'2"}'X` which will show you that in arg 4 there's a plain `'` inside the `'{…}'`. You probably need `"airflow variables --set my_var '{\"test\": \"test'"\\\'"'2\"}'"` which gives `airflow variables --set my_var '{"test": "test'\''2"}'` which means arg 4 = `{"test": "test'2"}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bash single quoted string **cannot** contain a single quote. You can't escape it. (ref 
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes)

Try this:

```
bash -c  "airflow variables --set my_var '{\"test\": \"test'\''2\"}'"
# .......................................1.................1..2....2
```

I numbered the matching single quoted strings. In between is a literal single quote.

Answer (score 0):

With version 3 you can specify an **array of commands**.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command

Answer (score 0):

You can use $ before the first single quote to be able to use escaped single quotes in the command.

So:

```
 docker exec -u root  airflowdags_webserver_1 bash -c  "airflow variables --set my_var $'{\"test\": \"test\'2\"}'"
```